# Execution Error - Handler 'lambda_handler' missing on module 'lambda_function'"

Tags: aws-lambda

Below is the code and the error that I'm getting while testing in Lambda. I'm a newbie in python & serverless. Please help. This is created for uploading the findings from the security hub to S3 for POC.

```py
import boto3
import json
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
import time
timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")

storedata = {}
client = boto3.client('securityhub')
_filter = Filters={
    'GeneratorId': [
        {
            'Value': 'arn:aws:securityhub:::ruleset/cis-aws-foundations-benchmark',
            'Comparison': 'PREFIX'
        }
    ],
}

response = client.get_findings(Filters=_filter)
storedata = json.dumps(response)
print(storedata)

def aws_session(region_name='eu-west-1'):
  return boto3.session.Session()

def upload_data_to_bucket(data, bucket_name, s3_key):
  session = aws_session()
  s3_resource = session.resource('s3')
  obj = s3_resource.Object(bucket_name, s3_key)
  obj.put(ACL='private', Body=data)

  s3_url = f"https://{bucket_name}.s3.amazonaws.com/{s3_key}"
  return s3_url

s3_url = upload_data_to_bucket(storedata, 'sdhkdhiufhasp', 'securityhub_findings.json')
print(s3_url)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we use Lambda we need to write our code inside the lambda_handler method
"def lambda_handler(event, context):" .

As you mentioned you are using lambda to run this code then probably the below code should work for you.

```
    import boto3
    import json
    from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
    import time
    import glob 
   
    client = boto3.client('securityhub')
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
     
     
     storedata = {}
     _filter = Filters={
        'GeneratorId': [
            {
                'Value': 'arn:aws:securityhub:::ruleset/cis-aws-foundations- 
       benchmark',
                'Comparison': 'PREFIX'
            }
        ],
      }

   def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = client.get_findings(Filters=_filter)
    storedata = json.dumps(response)
    print(storedata)

    save_file = open("/tmp/securityhub_findings.json", "w")
    save_file.write(storeddata)
    save_file.close()
 
    for name in glob.glob(/tmp/*):  
      s3.meta.client.upload_file(name, "you_bucket_name", name)
```